# java.net.UnknownHostException: www.terracotta.org

Tags: java, ehcache

Getting the following error when Jboss server start up.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.terracotta.org
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177) ~[na:1.6.0_11]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366) ~[na:1.6.0_11]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519) ~[na:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158) ~[na:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394) ~[na:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529) ~[na:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233) ~[na:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306) ~[na:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323) ~[na:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:837) ~[na:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:778) ~[na:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:703) ~[na:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1026) ~[na:1.6.0_11]
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.getUpdateProperties(UpdateChecker.java:108) [ehcache-core-2.6.5.jar:na]
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.doCheck(UpdateChecker.java:72) [ehcache-core-2.6.5.jar:na]
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.checkForUpdate(UpdateChecker.java:60) [ehcache-core-2.6.5.jar:na]
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.run(UpdateChecker.java:51) [ehcache-core-2.6.5.jar:na]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512) [na:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462) [na:1.6.0_11]
```

Any solution for the root cause would be helpful.

Comment: That's not a JBoss issue but the [Ehcache update checker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407169/ehcache-update-checker)

Answer (score 5):

Update your ehcache.xml and set updateCheck="false" in the root ehcache element, as follow:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="false" monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true" name="TestCache" >
```